# Solve the following questions. Let $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=\sin x$, $h(x)=\sqrt {x}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=\sin x$, $h(x)=\sqrt {x}$.

> a. Evaluate $h(g(\frac {\pi}{2}))$.
>
> b. Find $h(f(x))$.
>
> c. Find $f(g(h(x)))$.
>
> d. Find the domain of $g \circ f$.
>
> e. Find the range of $f \circ g$.

I know how to do b. and c., but I'm not sure about the rest.

Here are my answers for b. and c.:

> b. $\sqrt {x^3}$.
>
> c. $\sin^3\sqrt {x}$.

All advice and/or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you construct the formulas $(g \circ f)(x)$ and $(f \circ g)(x)$? Then you are just finding domain and range of those functions

Comment: I know how to construct the formulas, but I'm confused on how to find the domain and range of these compositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- a) $$\quad h(g(\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } ))=\sqrt { \sin { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  \right)  }  } =1$$
- d)$$ g\circ f=g\left( f\left( x \right)  \right) =\sin { \left( { x }^{ 3 } \right)  } \quad x\in R\\ $$
- e) $$ f\circ g=f\left( g\left( x \right)  \right) =\sin ^{ 3 }{ \left( x \right)  } \quad \in \left[ -1;1 \right] $$

Comment: Oh my, I think I messed up on d. and e. in my work, and I did not catch it. Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome)